# Codeigniter Selecting Data using CURDATE()

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

so here's what i'm trying to do with codeigniter using Active Record 
**What i'm trying to get**
 * show all the entry where date equal today

**Problem** 
i do  not get any result , just a blank page no error .
paraphas there's a mistake . please provide answer

in my datebase adate type is datetime

here is my model method

public function whois_here_today(){

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('attendance');
$this->db->where('adate', 'CURDATE()', FALSE);
$this->db->order_by('adate','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
 if ($query->num_rows() < 1) {
   echo "No REcords Found";
 }
  return $query->result();
```

}

and in my controller

```
public function index(){
    $data['workingemployees'] = $this->attendance_model->whois_here_today();
    $data['main_view'] = "app/testma";
    $this->load->view('app/header', $data);
  }
```

in the view

```
<?php foreach ($workingemployees as $working): ?>
  <?php echo $working->attendance_id; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: better to debug, print the generated query.

Comment: i think you need to format the date to compare . like this $this->db->where('date_format(adate,"%Y-%m-%d")', 'date_format(CURDATE(),"%Y-%m-%d")', FALSE);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to format the date to compare . Because your comparing datetime with date .  you need to extract the date from  `adate` .using date_format function  `date_format(adate,"%Y-%m-%d")`

```
$this->db->where('date_format(adate,"%Y-%m-%d")', 'CURDATE()', FALSE);
```

Comment: glad to help you @AdamRifau

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is correct. Please can you check your datatype of that "adate" field in database. Data type should be date or datetime. We dont need formating of CURDATE() function because default it returns 'Y-m-d' format.